# Python array manipulation, pi*[n+1]^2 - pi*[n]^2

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I'm writing a script to subtract the inside cylinder from the outside cylinder for multiple cylinders.

for example: `x = pi*[n+1]**2 - pi*[n]**2`

However I'm not sure how to get n to change each time from for example 1 - 4, i want to be able to change n and have the code run through the new values without having to change everything.

```
x = pi*[1]**2 - pi*[0]**2    
x = pi*[2]**2 - pi*[1]**2
x = pi*[3]**2 - pi*[2]**2
x = pi*[4]**2 - pi*[3]**2
```

I was trying to get a while loop to work but i cant figure out how to reference n without specifically stating which number in the array i want to reference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
rs = 0.2                                # Radius of first cylinder  
rc = 0.4                                # Radius of each cylinder (concrete) 
rg = 1                                  # Radius of each cylinder (soil)
BW = 3                                  # No. cylinders (concrete)
BG = 2                                  # No. cylinders (soil)
v1 = np.linspace(rs, rc, num=BW)        # Cylinders (concrete)
v2 = np.linspace(rc * 1.5, rg, num=BG)  # Cylinders (soil)

n = np.concatenate((v1, v2))            # Combined cylinders

for i in range(BW + BG):
    x = np.pi * (n[i + 1] ** 2) - np.pi * (n[i] ** 2)
```

Comment: Why can't you specifically state which array number to reference? Giving more context code would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for n in range(4): # 0 to 3
    x = pi*[n+1]**2 - pi*[n]**2 #[1] - [0], [2] - [1] and so on...
    # doSomething
```

If `[n]` is an index of an array with name `num`, replace `[n]` with 
`num[n]` like so:

```
for n in range(4): # 0 to 3
    x = pi*(num[n+1]**2) - pi*(num[n]**2) #[1] - [0], [2] - [1] and so on...
    # doSomething
```

If instead it was simply `n`, replace `[n]` with `n` like so:

```
for n in range(4): # 0 to 3
    x = pi*((n+1)**2) - pi*(n**2) #[1] - [0], [2] - [1] and so on...
    # doSomething
```

Comment: `pi*[n]**2` doesn't make any sense, since `[n]` is a one-element list. I think the questioner meant for that to be an indexing, so put `pi * some_sequence[n]**2` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response, however they're floats, is there a simple way to enable range to work with floats?

Comment: @ScottLines I do not understand what you mean by `enable range to work with floats?`

Comment: I get an error that 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: @ScottLines I am unable to reproduce that problem. Could you please enter your complete code?

Comment: Entered, I had the range value set as a float, changing that got rid of the error, however now it returns a single value instead of the value for each calculation

Answer (score 2):

Since your numbers are in a numpy array, it's much more efficient to use broadcast operations across the array (or slices of it), rather than writing a explicit loop and operating on individual items. This is the main reason to use numpy!

Try something like this:

```
# compute your `n` array as before

areas = pi * n**2   # this will be a new array with the area of each cylinder
area_differences = areas[1:] - areas[:-1]   # differences in area between adjacent cylinders
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
for i, value in enumerate(n[:-1]):
    print(np.pi * (n[i + 1] ** 2) - np.pi * (value ** 2))
```

For me it prints:

```
0.157079632679
0.219911485751
0.628318530718
2.0106192983
```

Perhaps you want this:

```
>>> values = [np.pi * (n[i + 1] ** 2) - np.pi * (value ** 2)
                          for i, value in enumerate(n[:-1])]
>>> values
[0.15707963267948971, 0.2199114857512855, 0.62831853071795885, 2.0106192982974673]
```

Lets explain it:

- we must get all elements in the list but the last, because `n[i + 1]` fails for the last item, so we use `n[0:-1]` (we are allowed omit the start of the slice if it is 0 or the end if it is equal or greater than `len(n)`).
- `enumerate(a_list)` returns something resembling a list of pairs in the form
  `[(0, a_list[0]), (1, a_list[1]), ..., (n, a_list[n)]`
- `for i, value in ...` unpacks each pair into variables named `i` and `value`
- `[something for something in a_list]` returns a new list. You may do calculations, and filter the values. For example, if you want a list of the square of the even integers bellow 10:
  `>>> [x * x for x in range(10) if x % 2 == 1]`
  `[1, 9, 25, 49, 81]`

Comment: That works quite well, I need to save the values in an array instead of printing them.

Comment: Updated. The secret is skipping the last value (n[:-1]) because it lacks a next item. This syntax of the list comprehension in the last snippet is inspired by the set-builder notation in math, so it must be familiar if you are into maths.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I'm after.

Answer (score -1):

I think this should provide the results you are looking for:

```
rs = 0.2                                # Radius of first cylinder
rc = 0.4                                # Radius of each cylinder (concrete) 
rg = 1                                  # Radius of each cylinder (soil)
BW = 3                                  # No. cylinders (concrete)
BG = 2                                  # No. cylinders (soil)
v1 = np.linspace(rs, rc, num=BW)        # Cylinders (concrete)
v2 = np.linspace(rc * 1.5, rg, num=BG)  # Cylinders (soil)

n = np.concatenate((v1, v2))

results = []
for i, v in enumerate(n):
    if i+1 < len(n):
        results.append(pi * n[i+1] ** 2 - pi * v ** 2)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: That provides exactly what I'm after, is there a simple way to change it so it saves the values in the array instead of overwriting it?